# Looking for specific help with networking iTunes with Air and Home Theatre PC

Tags: itunes, mac, network, sharing, pc

Let me explain my set up. I have a home theater PC that houses all my music files (about 500 gigs worth of music) but right now it just works as a server in that regard since I play all the music using my macbook air and itunes that streams the files to my receiver.
I have quite a good sound system and so I guess my first question is how much fidelity am I losing by streaming the signal? Almost all of my music library is lossless and obviously I would like to get the most out of that quality. Does anyone have any expertise or insight to quality lost via streaming?

If it's the case, I would like to look for solutions to get the most out of my set-up. I love using my macbook air as a "remote" for itunes as from anywhere in the house I can browse the library and play an album so I do not want to lose this fuctionality. Is it possible for me to, say, set up itunes on my home theater PC and host the library there (since it has a direct optical audio output straight to the receiver and would not need to stream) and then still use my Air as a "remote?"

Also, if I need to switch the host iTunes to the PC, is there an easy/headache free way of doing it so the PC iTunes will immediately recognize the old library and I won't need to do any new importing?  Especially since the old library is already stored on the PC.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is technically two independent questions. One about AirPlay streaming quality and one about transferring your iTunes library to a different computer. You should really edit this question to address one of them specifically and then create another question for the separate issue. Make sure your title summarizes the issue as well. Doing these things will give you the best chance of receiving an answer.